# tmpreaper, --protect and a non-root user

Tags: linux, tmpwatch

I'm a little confused. I have a download directory that I want to remove all files older then 30 days with tmpreaper. Just one problem, the directory in question is a separate partition with a lost+found directory, of course I need to keep it so I added  `--protect 'lost+found'`, the problem is that tmpreaper outputs:

```
error: chdir() to directory 'lost+found' (inode 11) failed: Permission denied
(PID 30604) Back from recursing down `lost+found'.
Entry matching `--protect' pattern skipped. `lost+found'
```

I have tried with other pattern like lost* and so on... I'm running tmpreaper as a non-root user because there is no reason for superuser privileges because I own all files (except lost+found).

Are I'm forced to run tmpreaper as root? Or are my shell-skills not as good as I thought?
I guess the problem is:

```
tmpreaper  will  chdir(2) into each of the directories you've 
specified for cleanup, and check for files matching the 
<shell_pattern> there.  It then builds a list of them,  and
uses that to protect them from removal.
```

Any thought and/or advice?

The command I'm trying to run is something like

```
$ /usr/sbin/tmpreaper -t --protect 'lost+found' 30d /mydir 1> /dev/null
error: chdir() to directory `lost+found' (inode 11) failed: Permission denied
```

Edit:

Redmumba noticed that the return code is still zero, and the files are removed. I must have had some other issues before because nothing was removed when I wrote this post. Anyway it's working now, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `lost+found` directory is file system specific and, even if you change the permissions, they will automatically be reverted back to `root:root` on a remount (or possibly even sooner).  However, because it sounds like you DON'T want to remove things there, it sounds like it may be a problem with the directory you're specifying.

For example, lets say you're removing the files inside `/tmp`, which is on a separate partition.  If you run `tmpreaper --protect 'lost+found' /tmp/*`, it will `chdir` into `/tmp/lost+found` *then* apply the shell glob--but it will fail with the permissions issue you saw.  When you specify the directory for `tmpreaper`, just use the parent directory--i.e., `tmpreaper --protect 'lost+found' /tmp`.

Hopefully that's your problem... if not, update with more information (such as the exact command you're using) and we can try and get you back on track!

EDIT: So I set it up locally, and I noticed that it finishes successfully.  It appears that it only prints out the error message, but does not react to it--i.e., it returns 0, indicating success.  I originally assumed it was failing, but that doesn't seem to be the case.  It sounds like filing a bug might be in order with details, as I wouldn't imagine that this is intended behavior.

Comment: Yes, I don't want to remove anything from lost+found. I have updated the question with a example.

Comment: Hm, I updated my response; the command finishes correctly, but shouldn't be displaying an error message--especially since it even says that it matches the protect rule.